# React native connect function not passing action to child component through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am just getting familiarized with redux and have been reading that I am supposed to pass in action creators through the parent of the app, and through mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, and the connect function I should be able to pass actions. However, when I call in the child component this.props. the function is nonexistent, so it seems that it is not being passed properly.

I would greatly appreciate assistance.

Note: I left out some things like imports and the reducer to be more concise.

login.js:

```
export function login(token, id) {
  console.log('login action');
  return {
    type: 'LOG_IN',
    token,
    id,
  };
}
```

index.ios.js:

```
import * as actionCreators from './actions/login'

const store = createStore(RootReducer, undefined, autoRehydrate());
persistStore(store);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
      token: '',
      id: '',
      store: store,
    };
  }

  render() {    
    return (

    <Provider store={ state.store }>
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <LoginView/>
      </View>
    </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App); 

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    token: state.token,
    id: state.id
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({actionCreators}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

loginView.js:

```
export class LoginView extends View {

  static propTypes = {}

  static defaultProps = {}

  constructor(props) {
    console.log(props);
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: '',
      token: '',
      id: '',
    }
    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
  }

  onLogin() {
    console.log("on login1");
    this.props.login({token: this.state.token, id: this.state.id});
    console.log("on login");
  }
```

And basically what happens is that when the onLogin() function is evoked directly above, it states that this.props.login is not a function. What is the reasoning for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're connecting the App component, so that will have `this.props.onLogin()`.  However, you're not passing `onLogin` as a prop to `<LoginView />`.  You need to either render `<LoginView onLogin={this.props.onLogin} />`, or connect LoginView also and include `onLogin` as part of that component's connection.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I was using this guide for my implementation: https://medium.com/@MKulinski/react-redux-basics-a36914c0035d#.76dv77xlp
It made it sound like I would not need to pass it as a prop to the component like you stated. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yeah, the wording in that article is bad.  A React component doesn't get props magically - they have to be handed down from somewhere.  `connect` generates a wrapper component that passes data props and function props down to your "real" component.  So yes, either explicitly pass the `onLogin` method from `App` to `LoginView`, or connect `LoginView` directly and give it `onLogin` in `mapDispatch`.

Comment: Also FYI, I keep a big list of links to high-quality tutorials and articles on React, Redux, and related topics, at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links .  Lots of good info and examples linked from there.

Comment: Much thanks for the help and resources! I'm sure it will come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
return bindActionCreators({actionCreators}, dispatch);
```

should be:

```
return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
```

"actionCreators" is already an object. By passing it inside another set of curly braces, it is being interpreted as the syntax for ES6 shorthand property names.  What you are actually passing is a new object that look like this:

```
{
  actionCreators: {
    login: ... // your action is buried here
  }
}

// ^^ which would get mapped to this.props.actionsCreators.login (wrong)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that did not fix the error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

seems redux connect in react native to bind state in components  thase days is using

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
...
class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 
// do your things.. 
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(this.props);
  }
  render () {
....
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return { user: state.user };
 };
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```